# Stored procedure executing but not able to access data in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures, data-access-layer

I have a stored procedure that executes perfectly in SQL Server. However I am not able to access the rows that are return by it in asp.net from Data Access Layer

My `DataAccessLayer` code is as follows:

```
 public List<AdvancePaymentRep> getPaymentAdvanceData(int? InternalCompany = 0, string Currency = "", DateTime? InvoiceDateFrom = null, DateTime? InvoiceDateTo = null, DateTime? AdvDateDueFrom = null, DateTime? AdvDateDueTo = null)
    {
      CreateConnectionString();
      List<AdvancePaymentRep> paymentAdvanceCollection = new List<AdvancePaymentRep>();
      SqlDataReader rdrval = null;
      SqlCommand command1 = sqlConnection.CreateCommand();
      command1.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
      command1.CommandText = "[dbo].[NST_GetDataForAdvancePaymentReport]";

      if (InternalCompany != 0)
      {

        SqlParameter parametersInternalCompany = new SqlParameter();
        parametersInternalCompany.ParameterName = "@AlhInternalCie";
        parametersInternalCompany.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Int;
        parametersInternalCompany.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        parametersInternalCompany.Value = InternalCompany;
        command1.Parameters.Add(parametersInternalCompany);
      }

      SqlParameter parametersCurrency = new SqlParameter();
      parametersCurrency.ParameterName = "@AlhCurrency";
      parametersCurrency.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar;
      parametersCurrency.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
      parametersCurrency.Value = Currency;
      command1.Parameters.Add(parametersCurrency);

      if (InvoiceDateFrom != Convert.ToDateTime("01/01/0001 00:00:00"))
      {

        SqlParameter parametersInvoiceDateFrom = new SqlParameter();
        parametersInvoiceDateFrom.ParameterName = "@AldDtCreatedFrom";
        parametersInvoiceDateFrom.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Date;
        parametersInvoiceDateFrom.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        parametersInvoiceDateFrom.Value = InvoiceDateFrom;
        command1.Parameters.Add(parametersInvoiceDateFrom);
      }

      if (InvoiceDateTo != Convert.ToDateTime("01/01/0001 00:00:00"))
      {
        SqlParameter parametersInvoiceDateTo = new SqlParameter();
        parametersInvoiceDateTo.ParameterName = "@AldDtCreatedTo";
        parametersInvoiceDateTo.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Date;
        parametersInvoiceDateTo.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        parametersInvoiceDateTo.Value = InvoiceDateTo;
        command1.Parameters.Add(parametersInvoiceDateTo);

      }

      if (AdvDateDueFrom != Convert.ToDateTime("01/01/0001 00:00:00"))
      {
        SqlParameter parametersInvoiceDateDueFrom = new SqlParameter();
        parametersInvoiceDateDueFrom.ParameterName = "@InvhDtDueFrom";
        parametersInvoiceDateDueFrom.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Date;
        parametersInvoiceDateDueFrom.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        parametersInvoiceDateDueFrom.Value = AdvDateDueFrom;
        command1.Parameters.Add(parametersInvoiceDateDueFrom);
      }


      if (AdvDateDueTo != Convert.ToDateTime("01/01/0001 00:00:00"))
      {
        SqlParameter parametersInvoiceDateDueTo = new SqlParameter();
        parametersInvoiceDateDueTo.ParameterName = "@InvhDtDueTo";
        parametersInvoiceDateDueTo.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Date;
        parametersInvoiceDateDueTo.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        parametersInvoiceDateDueTo.Value = AdvDateDueTo;
        command1.Parameters.Add(parametersInvoiceDateDueTo);
      }

      try
      {
        if (sqlConnection == null)
        {
          sqlConnection.Open();
        }
        rdrval = command1.ExecuteReader(); // Getting HasRows = false out here
```

EDIT : Have solved the issue there was some problem with how i had supplied the

Comment: can you paste your SP's code and output here? that will help in answering the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last command in your SP should be a `SELECT` command. Else, you get other results such as the number of rows affected and such. Management Studio is still able to display rows created from one of the `SELECT`s in your SP but actually they are not the first "thing" that is returned when you call an ADO.NET command against that SP.

Answer (score 0):

After your

```
rdrval = command1.ExecuteReader();
```

You'll need to do something like

```
while (rdrval.Read()) 
{
  //do something
}
```

Comment: I agree this is required, but at the bottom of his code he says HasRows =false.

Comment: very true - @Ofer is most likely right...something is off with the stored procedure.